# autoClose of tooltipster is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

On page load the tooltipster shows, but i want it to stay there unless user clicks on the link in tooltipster content. The problem is, when i hover on the tooltipster and go outside it, without clicking the link, the tooltipster closes (i think autoClose fails).

How can i prevent this closing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tooltip1").tooltipster ({
                theme: '.tooltipster-light',
                position: 'right',
                animation: 'grow',
                maxWidth: '160',
                autoClose: false,
                interactive: true,
                contentAsHTML: true,
               //timer: 10000,
                delay: 1000,
                content: '<a href="notified" class="tooltip_display" data-remote="true" style="color:#0988E4"><u>Do not show again</u></a>',
                 });
        $(".tooltip1").tooltipster("show");

     });
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/2h00Lj9y/) with your exact code, works as expected.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin this tooltipster is then not fulfilling my purpose, is there any way i can override or force the functionality to prevent it from autoClosing

Comment: It's not closing on my machine - I've checked Chrome 37, Firefox 31, IE 11, 10, 9 - it appears on load and doesn't close after hover.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after few mins i figured out that my tooltipster version is too old and all i had to do is update it and autoClose worked... try that

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h00Lj9y/1/) with your code and added the following to hide the tooltip on hover:

```
// Hide on hover
$(".tooltip1").hover(function(){
         $(this).tooltipster('hide'); 
});
```